# How to update all document in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Now, It's update only one document ,I'ld like to update all document where status is 0 in mongodb with node.js ORM.

```
MessageUser.update(
{
  status : "0",
},
{
  $set : {status : "1"}
},
{multi:true}
,function(err, result){
  if(!err){
    console.log('updated');
  }
});
```

Comment: Query seems fine. It'll update all documents but only `console.log()` once.

Comment: sorry, I forget to restart server, It's work now, thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that sometimes the status is set to 0, the number, and other times it's set to '0' the string?

Comment: I don't think it'll work, update String instead of number type, but I was using String type for status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry , this query is okay ,I didn't check in my table carefully.

```
MessageUser.update({
    status : "0",
  },
  {
    $set : {status : "1"}
  },
 {  multi:true  },
 function(err, result){
  if(!err){
    console.log('updated');
  }
});
```